# Gorm take huge time to retrieve data from Postgres

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

```
23:28:45 | 200 | 20.294s |       127.0.0.1 | GET     | /api/user/cart/product/all
```

From Cart product, I retrieve cart with Cart products. Though Cart has only one Cart with One product. But it takes too much time to retrieve.

```
var cart model.Cart
    if err := model.DB.Select([]string{"id"}).Preload("CartProduct", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select([]string{"cart_id", "id", "quantity", "seller_product_id", "seller_product_variation_id"})
    }).Preload("CartProduct.SellerProduct", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select([]string{"id", "name", "slug", "selling_price", "product_price", "offer_price", "offer_price_start", "offer_price_end", "quantity", "next_stock", "description"})
    }).Preload("CartProduct.SellerProduct.SellerProductImage", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select([]string{"image", "seller_product_id"}).Where("display = ?", true)
    }).Preload("CartProduct.SellerProductVariation", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select([]string{"id", "image", "product_price", "selling_price", "quantity", "seller_product_id"})
    }).Preload("CartProduct.SellerProductVariation.SellerProductVariationValues", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select([]string{"id", "name", "description", "attribute_id", "seller_product_variation_id"})
    }).Preload("CartProduct.SellerProductVariation.SellerProductVariationValues.Attribute", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB { return db.Select([]string{"id", "name"}) }).Where("user_id = ?", c.Locals("user_id")).First(&cart); err.Error != nil {
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusNoContent)
    }
    return c.JSON(cart)
```

Here is my connection

```
dsn := "user=postgres password=123456 dbname=bongobitan port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Dhaka"
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to database")
    }
```

How can I speed up my code?